# Exception when replace fragment again

Tags: android, android-fragments

I develop an app, where 5(general) fragments.

In main activity I replace fragment by pressing a button(5 button in main activity) each fragment load into FrameLayout in mainActivity.

When I press 1-2-3-4 button - it's ok, fragments changes more time..
But, when I press 5 button more time - app crashes with NPE exception.

Press more time means - I click on button 5, then click on another button, then click on 5 button again - crashes.

Code 5's button in mainActivity:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.appFragmentContainer, fragmentMyAccount);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Code of fragment, which loading when press 5 button:
It's fragment, where page adapter in which I load 3 fragments.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Fragment class:

```
public class Fragment_my_account extends Fragment {

    ViewPager mViewPager;
    TabPagerAdapter mTabPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_account, container,false);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mTabPagerAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mTabPagerAdapter);

        return v;
    }
}
```

Page adapter code:

```
public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                //Fragement for panic btn settings tab
                return new Fragment_a();
            case 1:
                //Fragment for tracking settings
                return new Fragment_b();
            case 2:
                //Fragment for general settings
                return new Fragment_c();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Page " + position;
    }

}
```

I want, when I pressing on button 5 - load three fragments(one of three), which I can change motion finger from left to right.

Anybody knows, what I doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT 1:
Exception

```
05-01 16:42:00.113    1492-1492/my.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getFragment(FragmentManager.java:585)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.restoreState(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:211)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onRestoreInstanceState(ViewPager.java:1286)
            at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:12093)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2582)
            at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:12071)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:465)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:979)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:456)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post your stack trace and the missing relevant code

Comment: ^^ - post your logcat please

Comment: I've edited post. Add log with exception.